# Use "oneOf" in OAS 3.0 for multiple criteria of "required" properties

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-codegen

Needed to make use of "oneOf" in OAS 3.0 to support multiple criteria .

My model object looks like this -

```
DiskDataSourceSpec:
      title: "Source corresponding to the Volume Disk"
      description: "Spec comprising the source corresponding to the Volume Disk."
      type: "object"
      oneOf:
        - required:
            - containerUUID
        - required:
            - volumeDiskUUID
      properties:
        containerUUID:
          type: "string"
          description: "Storage container UUID on which the disk must be created."
        volumeDiskUUID:
          type: "string"
          description: "An existing disk whose contents must be cloned."
```

However this way of writing "oneOf" is seemingly not supported in OAS 3.0.

I can use **$ref** under **oneOf** to support different models, but here I need this to be applied just on properties.

Need help in finding out what is the correct way of carrying this out ?

Comment: Your definition is perfectly valid in OAS3, what do you mean by "not supported" - do you have problems with certain tools i.e. codegen?

Comment: @Helen Yes, the codegen does not seem to generate it properly. It just generates a class with no attributes at all. Just a default constructor is present. If I remove the `oneOf` portion entirely, both the properties are part of the class perfectly.